# Close reason says 'programmining' instead of 'programming'

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just noticed a spelling mistake in one of the close reasons. (Consult freehand circle.)

[image]

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This typo has been corrected in the form of a new close reason. The reason text has remained exactly the same, the only change being the title change.